# Adobe AIR for Android - Open native facebook app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, actionscript-3, air

So I've been trying to figure out a way to open the native android facebook app from my Adobe AIR game but couldn't find a solution yet.

Basically I am interesting in letting my users open my game's facebook page and be able to click the like button.

My current solution is to open a webview but that is not good enough because users will have to enter their facebook login details.

So I just need them to open my game's page directly in their facebook app without needing to enter login details in a webview.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `navigateToURL(new URLRequest("fb://profile/your_page_id"));`

You can get your page id by going to your Facebook page and pressing the Edit Page button. It will be in the browser url bar. E.g. `https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=261615207268847&tab=public`

The id is 261615207268847 so `navigateToURL(new URLRequest("fb://profile/261615207268847"));`

Comment: Great, this works! I've been looking for a way to do this for months! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to track if users have liked the page? I would like to reward them with in-game virtual currency.

Comment: Great. Glad that helps. 

I know it is possible to receive a callback when someone likes your page. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Not quite sure how to integrate it into Adobe AIR off the top of my head but it would be a good place to start. Perhaps worth a new question.

If you're happy with my answer could you mark it as correct? I'm hunting for badges! - Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks. I clicked the check mark, I think that's what I need to do?

Comment: This method no longer works. My app launched in late November 2013 used the vanity URL path successfully until I recently noticed it no longer opens my company page but instead only opens the user's timeline. Yesterday I tested the "fb:" method with my page's ID and got the same result. Tested on iPhone 4 and ipad mini, both still running iOS 6
AIR SDK 3.9